# Strange effect in the SphericalPlot3D

Tags: special-functions, trigonometry, code, error-trapping

I found something odd in Mathematica when using the `SphericalPlot3D` command.

Ranges for $x,y∈[0,2 \pi]$ are the same. All I do is swap sine and cosine.

> [image]

But when I additionally change the intervals in places, everything "normalizes".

> [image]

If this is an internal error in Mathematica, I ask developers and users to pay attention. In theory, this should give exactly the same result, however...

```
SphericalPlot3D[Sin[x] Cos[y], {x, 0, 2 Pi}, {y, 0, 2 Pi}, 
  BoxRatios -> {1, 1, 1}, ImageSize -> Tiny];

SphericalPlot3D[Cos[x] Sin[y], {x, 0, 2 Pi}, {y, 0, 2 Pi}, 
  BoxRatios -> {1, 1, 1}, ImageSize -> Tiny];
```

I have version 12 of Mathematica and Windows 10.

Comment: Is there a special reason for using x,y instead of $\theta$, $\phi$ in the context of `SphericalPlot3D`?

Comment: @Syed There is no particular reason, it's just for your own convenience. Any letters can be used.

Comment: While specifying the function to be plotted, a change in the positions of x, y  changes their meanings?

Comment: There are a lot of confusion here. Once corrected, everything is fine. Voting to close. First of all, the range of the first argument is not $[0,2\pi]$, but $[0,\pi]$. Second, one should consider that the negative part of the function is not plotted. Third,  `Sin[x] Cos[y]`  and `Cos[x] Sin[y]` are not equivalent because the two angles have very different meaning.

Comment: @yarchik I already learned that there are nuances with ranges. So yes, the functions are not equivalent. They are equivalent if the intervals are the same. I already talked about this topic in the chat and I had the following thought: is it possible to convert the coordinates manually and expand the range of angles by converting the ranges of arc tangents? I just don't know how to then plot this graph in the right coordinates.

Comment: Yes, it would be possible, but what is the end goal you are trying to achieve? Maybe you should explain a bit more your real problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We can compare the two cases in `Cartesian` coordinate.

```
r1[θ_, φ_] = Sin[θ] Cos[φ];
r2[θ_, φ_] = Sin[φ] Cos[θ];
```

```
result1=FromSphericalCoordinates[{r, θ, φ}] /.r -> r1[θ, φ]
result2=FromSphericalCoordinates[{r, θ, φ}] /.r -> r2[θ, φ]
```

$$\left\{\sin ^2(\theta ) \cos ^2(\varphi ),\sin ^2(\theta ) \sin (\varphi ) \cos (\varphi ),\sin (\theta ) \cos (\theta ) \cos (\varphi )\right\}$$

$$\left\{\sin (\theta ) \cos (\theta ) \sin (\varphi ) \cos (\varphi ),\sin (\theta ) \cos (\theta ) \sin ^2(\varphi ),\cos ^2(\theta ) \sin
   (\varphi )\right\}$$

It means that `r1[θ_, φ_] = Sin[θ] Cos[φ]` and `r2[θ_, φ_] = Sin[φ] Cos[θ]` is different.